# Override public int hashCode() using BigInteger

Tags: java, collections, hashcode

A BigInteter is too big to be converted into an integer. But I have to store objects with an id (SHA 512) in a `HashMap` and need a hash function without many collisions.

I tried this. however, I am not sure if there is no clustering somewhere.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    Advertisement other = (Advertisement) obj;
    return this.getId().equals(other.getId());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new BigInteger(getId(), 16).hashCode();
}
```

would be a cast to an integer (bi.intValue()) more efficient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't try to reinvent the wheel - simply use `getId().hashCode()`:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getId().hashCode();
}
```

[`String.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) uses an efficient, high-quality hashing algorithm, so it's the best choice. And it makes your code simpler, which is always a good thing.